# Can we initialise static variable inside constructor?

Tags: java

I have the following code snippet:

```
class Constructor {

  static String str;

  public void Constructor() {
      System.out.println("In constructor");
      str = "Hello World";
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      Constructor c=new Constructor();
      System.out.println(str);
  }
}
```

Its output is null even though the string is initialized inside the constructor.

Why is that so?

Comment: public void Constructor(){ is not a constructor,its an ordinary method

Comment: As for your question: you can, but you should not. This is extremely bad style.

Comment: But in my opinion it doesn't make any sense to want to initialize a static variable inside a constructor? A static variable can be accessed without an object, therefore the variable shouldn't be static if you need to initialize in the constructor.

Comment: It makes no sense to "initialize" a static member in a constructor. It will get reinitialized every time you create a new instance. This is at best redundant and at worst just plain wrong.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the comments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments `public void Constructor(){` is not a constructor because constructors do not have return type.As your `Constructor` is of void so its not an constructor

Remove the void keyword

```
class Constructor {

static String str;

public Constructor(){
    System.out.println("In constructor");
    str="Hello World";
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Constructor c=new Constructor();

    System.out.println(str);

}


}
```

output:Hello World

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying

Comment: @abhi1489 Welcome. You can accept one of the solutions here which you think helped you most.

Answer (score 9):

`public void Constructor()` is not a constructor.. it's a *void method*. If you remove the `void`, it should work as intended

Answer (score 2):

Also as a side-note: you may use a static-block to initialize static variables. In your case like so:

```
static {
    str="Hello World";
}
```

This means you only initialize the variable once and not every time the constructor is executed.

Answer (score 1):

> I have the following code snippet whose output is null even though the string is initialised inside the constructor

A constructor ***do not*** have return type. Your current so called constructor comes with a return type of `void` hence it is no longer a constructor, but a method of your class.

Try again with:

```
public Constructor(){  //void removed
    System.out.println("In constructor");
    str="Hello World";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

If we are using static variable then we don't have need to create an object and also a constructor which is used to initialize value of instance variable on place of default values. We can use **static block** to initialize **static variable** which always executes first before the main() method in Java.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. But you should not.

Let me elaborate it in detail.

When you are initializing its value inside constructor; you are actually assigning some value to it. This will always be assigned whenever you create object of your class (which you not what you intended to do when you thought of initializing static data member right).

Here static blocks comes to rescue us.

*Static blocks are executed whenever class is loaded into memory by JVM*. Hence once your class is loaded, whichever assignments you have defined inside your static block happens for the first and last time until your class is there in memory.

Hence its ideal to use static initializer blocks always to initialize static data members.

In your case introduce below code snippet inside your class

```
static {
    str = "Hello World";
}
```